# TCP Unix send() very slow C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Edit: Turned out to be a problem with my embedded ethernet adapter.  Works well now.  Thanks everyone.

When I send a file over a tcp socket it takes a long time (~4 seconds for 1.5M bytes) for the transfer to complete.  The same file travels almost instantly over tftp.  I know tftp uses UDP, which should be faster, but I still think my transfer is WAY too slow.  I'm connected 100Mbps half duplex, through a crossover cable.  The sender is UNIX and the receiver is .Net on Windows TcpClient.

So, what does everyone think?  Do I need some better C code?  Is there maybe something wrong with the network?

Here is my C code:

```
int main(void)
{
    //some initializing stuff
    int AcceptSocket, ClientRecvSocket;

    alen = sizeof(fsin);
    int AcceptSocket = passiveTCP("20075", 10);
    //Wait for client connections, and spawn a new thread to communicate with each one
    pszRecvBuf = malloc((size_t) BUFSIZE);
    while (1)
    {
        ClientRecvSocket = accept(AcceptSocket, &fsin, &alen);
        printf("\nDebug: Accepted Connection\n");
        if (ClientRecvSocket < 0)
        {
            sprintf(szStr, "Error accepting client connection : %d",
                    ClientRecvSocket);
            perror(szStr);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\nDebug: Starting Thread\n");
            ThreadStatus = pthread_create(&ClientThread, NULL, ClientRecv,
                    (void *) &ClientRecvSocket);
            pthread_join(ClientThread, NULL);
        }
    }
}

void *ClientRecv(void *ClientSocket)
{
    pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
    int Socket = *(int *) ClientSocket;

    unsigned char *file_buffer;
    file_buffer = malloc(1572864 * sizeof(unsigned char));

    //set file data to something

    SendLen = send(Socket, file_buffer, 1572864 * sizeof(unsigned char), 0);
    shutdown(Socket, SHUT_RDWR);
    free(file_buffer);
}
int passiveTCP(char *service, int qlen)
{
     return passivesock(service, "tcp", qlen);
}
```

Comment: `passiveTCP`, `AcceptSocket` etc are all non-standard. We can't even begin to approach this problem.

Comment: AcceptSocket is an int.  I didn't realize that passiveTCP is not standard.

Comment: Before looking at your code, you should probably use something along the lines of `netcat`, or even `ftp` to make sure that your network connection is not at fault. Half duplex connections can be *difficult*...

Comment: Note that `sizeof(unsigned char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so you don't need to multiply with it.

Comment: @Philip, I know, but I like to stay in the habit.

Comment: All right, I tried a usb->ethernet adapter and it goes much faster.  There must be something wrong with my embedded.  Problem solved, thanks for everyone's time.

Answer (score 1):

At a glance, looking at it, within your function `ClientRecv`, you're consuming too much resources...

```
unsigned char *file_buffer;
file_buffer = malloc(1572864 * sizeof(unsigned char));
```

You're allocating memory for that, but where is it gone to.... should try free'ing the pointer to that buffer....

As a matter of interest to serve and help others, is that some kind of wrapper framework you're using and please specify what kind.... as I strongly suspect that it is a non-standard software you are using - perhaps that software has certain "issues"?

Comment: I do free the memory, that's a simplified version of my code.

I'm not using any kind of wrapper that I know of.

Comment: Care to show the internals of those wrappers, like what is `PassiveTCP`, what is AcceptSocket/ClientRecvSocket... they sound a bit convoluted ... and not standard....

Comment: Also, in that case, if you say you do free the memory, please amend your question to point out that so as not to mislead others into wasting their time in answering along the similar lines... "I do not see free in there...." etc

Comment: I've made those changes and added the definition of passiveTCP().  Thanks for your input, I tried to make it as clear as I could, but it's much better now.

Comment: @DuneCat: you're getting the hang of it now \0/ oh and welcome to SO! :D

Comment: To whoever downvoted this answer - it is philosophy of this site to include a *reason* why this was downvoted.. as you can see, this was answered relatively 43 mins ago and things have changed since then... :P

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting full duplex instead.

Since TCP requires an acknowledgement for (roughly) each transmitted packet, your half duplex link will have to stop transmitting to handle receipt of those ACKs.  That could manifest as collisions, causing packet loss and ultimately triggering TCP's congestion controls.

Comment: uClinix that I'm using isn't cooperating with my demands for full duplex.

Comment: The German WP entry for "Full-duplex Ethernet" states that if one end of the connection uses auto-negotiation while the other end enforces full-duplex, then the auto-negotiation end will only detect half-duplex, resulting in lots of collisions.

Comment: @DuneCat: Should state uClinix in your question to make it even more clearer and attract someone who has knowledge of uClinix to your question....

Comment: @Philip, yes, that's right.  You must either set both ends to auto, or both to fixed 100-full.